# A lambda expression with a expression body cannot be converted to an expression tree C# entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have an entity table with below model

```
   public class VulnerabilityImportFileLog
    {
        public Collection<Vulnerability> Vulnerability { get; set; }
    }
```

Trying to return an string value using the select statement in the entity framework query

```
var vulnerabilityImportFileLogSelect = vulnerabilityImportFileLogQuery
        .Select(vulnerabilityImportFileLog =>
            new VulnerabilityImportedScansListViewDto
            {
                AssetName = vulnerabilityImportFileLog.Vulnerability.Select(y =>
                    {
                        if (y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.HostIPAssetId.HasValue)
                            return y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.HostIPAsset.Title;
                        else if (y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.DomainAssetId.HasValue)
                            return y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.DomainAsset.Title;
                        else
                            return y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.HostIPOrDomain;
                    }
                ).Distinct().ToList()
            });
```

Where `AssetName` is of type `List<string>` and getting an exception as `A lamda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

[image]

An suggested answer was to use `AsEnumerable()`, but even that not solved the issue.

Comment: Did you put `.AsEnumerable()` immediately before `.Select(y => ...)` or immediately before `.Select(vulnerabilityImportFileLog => ...)`, or both places?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes I put mmediately before .Select, it didn't worked

Comment: When you put `.AsEnumerable()`, then `.Select` goes to another extension method which wants a plain `Func<,>` delegate, not an expression tree. Therefore, the error you ask about goes away in that case. When you say it did not "work", that is not very precise.

Comment: First off, what is `vulnerabilityImportFileLogQuery` in your case? Using `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` is a crutch and even if it does work can cripple your system. It would be `vulnerablilityImportFileLog.AsEnumerable().Vulnerability.Select(y => ...)` This would expecte that the various Asset and related entities are eager loaded to avoid lazy loading costs or null references.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by using linq query syntax with 'let' keyword:

```
AssetName = (from y in vulnerabilityImportFileLog.Vulnerability
    let resultString = y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.HostIPAssetId.HasValue
      ? y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.HostIPAsset.Title
      : y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.DomainAssetId.HasValue
      ? y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.DomainAsset.Title
      : y.AssetHostIPOrDomain.HostIPOrDomain
  select resultString
)
.ToList()
.Distinct();
```

Comment: Well I got this exception -  Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions.

Comment: @SanJaisy, try without `Distinct()`. If it works, do `Distinct` later on the client side.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv is there a way to do in the query, I can't do on the client-side

Comment: @SanJaisy, This is the question for EF team. They won't support such Eager Loading query. And why you cannot do that on the client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming vulnerabilityImportFileLogQuery is an `IQueryable<vulnerabilityImportFileLog>` then a typical way to fetch details from the associated Vulnerability relations would be via a `SelectMany`. Given you need to do substitution depending on what is available, one option would be to do a double-projection. The first pass selects and materializes just the details we want to inspect, then the second pass composes the results.

```
vulnerabilityImportFileLogQuery.SelectMany(x => new 
{
    x.Vulnerability.AssetHostIpOrDomain.HostIpOrDomain,
    HostIpAssetTitle = x.Vulnerability.AssetHostIpOrDomain.HostIpAsset.Title,
    DomainAssetTitle = x.Vulnerability.AssetHostIpOrDomain.DomainAsset.Title
}).ToList()
.Select(x => x.HostIpAssetTitle ?? DomainAssetTitle ?? HostIpOrDomain)
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

What this essentially does is fetch the 3 values, our default HostIpOrDomain value, and the Titles from the HostIpAsset and DomainAsset if they are available. EF will return #null if the entities aren't associated or the Title is #null. This query is materialized using the `ToList`, then from that we Select the title to use based on a null check, before taking our Distinct set.

Hopefully that gives you a few ideas as a starting point.